# Is there way to use PreferenceActivity without storing values in shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an android application that has uses few serializable classes
(I can store and load them in JSON format using Google Gson library and it works like a charm).

Now I want to provide way for user to edit those objects in fashion similar to PreferenceActivity - they contain few strings, ints and doubles and PreferenceScreen just seems ideal for editing them.

Is there a way to 'abuse' PreferenceActivity to provide UI for editing my objects without actually storing data in shared preferences?

For example - if there was some callback to override that is called just before saving data, I could extract data, assemble my object and somehow prevent Android from messing with preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would think if I really want to present objects editing with preferences UI since it might confuse a user.

If you still decide to go this way you can achieve it with:

1. Serialise every object in separate shared preference file and use preference activity how it is designed
2. Write own `PreferenceManager` and use reflection to replace private field in `PreferenceActivity`

The first one is straight forward and rather simple to implement, might have some performance implications. The second one might get tricky and probably requires more code to write.

I would still advice to revise decision to **"re-use"** `PreferenceActivity` for such case.

Comment: I think I will go with the first way. Few additional 'dummy' preferences will not hurt and they provide nice way of setting default values. I'm not worried about confusing user with UI because my objects in fact ARE preferences  - they are store calibration parameters for some electronic devices and sensors. I am developing application that serves as an interface to them. Calibrations are loaded from JSON files, but sometimes certain parameters need to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` is an interface, so you should be able to provide your own implementation that stores data however you like.  But the `PreferenceManager` used by `PreferenceFragment` only has a setter that takes a file name, not a custom implementation of `SharedPreferences`.

I looked into the source and found a roundabout way to use your own implementation.  `PreferenceFragment` uses its hosting `Activity` as the `Context` for constructing a `PreferenceManager`.  `PreferenceManager` subsequently calls `Context#getSharedPreferences(String, int)` to get the `SharedPreferences` that it will use.  Therefore, you can override `getSharedPreferences` in the activity hosting your `PreferenceFragment` and return your custom implementation.  Implementing `SharedPreferences` could be rather complicated since you'll also have to implement `SharedPreferences.Editor`, but it's doable.  And if there's any chance of your overridden `getSharedPreferences` being used anywhere else, you should document that it uses a different backing store.

In the Android O preview, there's a new interface called [`PreferenceDataStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceDataStore.html) and a new [setter in `PreferenceManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setPreferenceDataStore(android.preference.PreferenceDataStore)) that takes an instance of that interface.  `PreferenceDataStore` looks much simpler to implement than `SharedPreferences`.  But as I write this, most retailers are still selling L and M devices, so who knows when we'll see O.

Comment: PreferenceDataStore would be ideal - serialize directly to JSON and my problem is gone :) . Unfortunately it is not available and even if it was app has to be compatible with Jelly Bean so I cannot use any new goodies :(. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: That's an interesting way to go. I already implemented it using set of dummy preferences that are reset each time object is loaded an then serialized to JSON when PreferenceActivity ends. Whole goal of reusing PreferenceActivity for this was not having to reimplement anything big (like SharedPreferences). I will leave it as is now. If app will need to be updated sommetime in the future I will go with PreferenceDataStore.